# How to stop a service or a kafka consumer after it has been idle for a certain period of time?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer running continuously as a service . I've noticed it only runs for a certain period of time during the day. Instead of keeping it continuously running I want to set some kind of polling timeout for the consumer.

If the consumer doesn't consumes anything/idle for 10mins then I want to shut down the service. Is there some kind of polling timeout and signaling mechanism such as this in Kafka that I can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` and respective container property and its docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idleEventInterval

Comment: Also https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

Comment: Not that, to avoid unnecessary delays, you should `stop()` the container using a different thread to the one which emits the idle event. See `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler` for a technique to do that.